# Converting storage size String to long?

Tags: java, string, long-integer

In Java...
Assuming my input is a String for storage size that can vary. (ex. "1.2mb", "500kb", "4.5gb", "900b", etc.) I need to convert any input to bytes and store it as a long. The way I see it I would need to split up the string (ex. "1.2" and "mb", "500" and "kb", etc.) Then based on the second string I can determine how much to multiply by the first string by to get it to bytes.

1.) I am not sure how to split up the string. Idea I had was to reverse the string then get the 2nd character but that wouldn't work if the input was in bytes as the 2nd character would be a number in that case. Any ideas on how I can properly split this up?

2.) If there is some better way other than splitting up the string, like a some library or something that can just do the conversion for me. Seems like something that might/should exist.

Comment: Parsing the String using String class methods sounds like a reasonable approach. What have you tried?

Comment: What you're looking for is a "java unit converter". There are countless such libraries out there. Search a bit and look for one that matches your needs and has the correct license.

Answer (score -1):

Okay realized I was completely overthinking this. Solution I came up with was looping through the string using Character.IsLetter() to get the "kb", "b", "mb", etc.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could also achieve this by using a [regular expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) like this one:

```
([\d\.]+)\s*(\D*)
```

This consists of three parts
 1. `([\d\.]+)` - Find any character sequence containing only digits and the dot
 2. `\s*` - Allow whitespaces between the number and the unit
 3. `(\D*)` - The unit: anything that is not a digit

You can play around with this regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Awtlh6/1/)

And here is how you use the regular expression in java:

```java
List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("100", "500b", "1.2kb", "100 mb", "4.5Gb", "3.45tb");

//Lookup map for the factors
Map<String, Double> factors = new HashMap<>();
factors.put("kb",   Math.pow(10,3));
factors.put("mb",   Math.pow(10,6));
factors.put("gb",   Math.pow(10,9));
factors.put("tb",   Math.pow(10,12));

//Create the regex pattern
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<size>[\\d\\.]+)\\s*(?<unit>\\D*)");

for(String input : inputs){
    //Apply the regex pattern to the input string
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    //If it matches
    if(matcher.find()){

        //get the contents of our named groups
        String size = matcher.group("size");
        String unit = matcher.group("unit");

        //Parse and calculate the result
        Double factor = factors.getOrDefault(unit.toLowerCase(), 1d);
        double calculatedSize = Double.parseDouble(size) * factor;

        //Print the result
        System.out.printf("%s\t= %.0f bytes\n", input, calculatedSize);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
100     = 100 bytes
500b    = 500 bytes
1.2kb   = 1200 bytes
100 mb  = 100000000 bytes
4.5Gb   = 4500000000 bytes
3.45tb  = 3450000000000 bytes
```